# Como acessar o COOKIE em outra página?

Tags: php, cookies

Tenho um arquivo em que ele cria um cookie.
E tenho um outro arquivo em que chamo este cookie, só que ele me da esse erro:  **Undefined index: nome in**

Aqui esta o código do primeiro arquivo:

```
setcookie('nome', $dataNome', time() + (2 * 3600));
```

Aqui o do segundo:

```
echo $_COOKIE['nome'];
```

Conforme sugerido em comentário:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
[PHPSESSID] => 7t392fumpc1apivqmets57ig90
```

Comment: da um print_r($_COOKIE); para ver o que retorna e posta aqui

Comment: [PHPSESSID] => 7t392fumpc1apivqmets57ig90

Comment: Provavelmente é um problema de escopo do cookie. Tente colocar `setcookie("nome", $dataNome, time() + (2 * 3600), "/");`. Verifique o escopo do cookie nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>**PHP Explica**</sub>

> Uma vez que o cookie foi setado, ele pode ser acessado na próxima página através dos arrays $_COOKIE

---

<sub>Você criou o cookie com sucesso:</sub>

```
setcookie( 'nome' , $dataNome , time() + (2 * 3600) );
```

<sub>Mas para recuperar, somente na proxima atualização, pois ele não estará disponivel antes disso</sub>

```
echo $_COOKIE['nome'];
```

**Por este motivo dispara o erro `Undefined index`.**

---

Uma solução é criar um tipo de `storage` para os cookies.
Quando você criar um cookie, será guardado na classe e será criado pela função `setcookie`, e quando você requisitar a leitura, ele verificará se está em $_COOKIE ou se está na $storage.

Exemplo de uso:

```
Cookie::writer( 'nome' , 'Papa Charlie' );
Cookie::reader( 'nome' );
```

Classe cookie/storage

```
class Cookie
{
    private static $storage = array();

    public static reader( $key )
    {
        if( isset( $_COOKIE[ $key ] ) )
        {
            return $_COOKIE[ $key ];
        }
        else
        {
            if( isset( static::$storage[$key] ) )
            return static::$storage[$key];
        }
    }

    public static writer( $key, $value /* outros parametros de criação de cookie */ )
    {
        static::$storage[$key] = $value;
        setcookie( $key , $value , time() + ( 2 * 3600 ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Observação: `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` é deprecated e não deve ser mais utilizado.

Comment: Eu dei `copy-paste` apenas, valeu vou editar

Answer (score 3):

Certifique-se de que você não está enviando qualquer saída para o navegador antes da função `setcookie()`.

ob_start() deve parar o output antes do  "`setcookie ()`" de erro, mas não pode ser implementado corretamente.

Lembrando também de utilizar o `ob_end_flush()` no final da página.